# How to ignore ssl certificate warning or pass a self signed certificate (from inside gruntfile) during accessibility automation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, phantomjs

I am using the [grunt-accessibility](https://github.com/yargalot/grunt-accessibility) plugins to automate the reporting for `accessibility` errors. It works fine for normally, but when I try it on a site which has a `self signed certificate` (the kind which shows an `interim` page with some certificate security warning and a link to continue to the site if you still wish to), it reports the error on that `interim` page itself which is, of course an empty page:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Obviously I want to bypass this interim page and run `accessibility` on the actual page.

**What I was trying?**

I had tried the following (found from googling and from other `SO's` Q&A):

1. The infamous hack

   ```
   npm set strict-ssl false
   ```
2. Adding the imported certification path

   ```
   npm config set cafile="C:\path\to\cert.cer"
   ```
3. Adding `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"` (see `Grunfile` below)

From what I gather, `grunt-accessibility` uses `AccessSniff` which in turn uses `phantomjs`. Now, `phantomjs` has options to ignore such warnings by

> `--ignore-ssl-errors=[true|false]` ignores SSL errors, such as expired or self-signed certificate errors (default is false).

Above is the CLI options, which I am not able to pass from `Grunfile.js`. 
Can someone help me resolve or suggest another approach for the issue.

This is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = grunt => {
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

  grunt.initConfig({
    phantomjs: {
      // default: {
        options: {
          "ignore-ssl-errors": true,
          // tested here with different instructions as per comments 
          // below from users on this site, such as
          // "--ignore-ssl-errors": true (-- hyphen)
          // "ignore-ssl-errors": "true" ("true" as string)
          "ssl-protocol": "any",
          "ssl-certificates-path": "C:/path/to/cert.cer"
        }
      // }
    },
    accessibility: {
      options: {
        force: true,
        accessibilityLevel: 'WCAG2AAA',
        browser: true // tested with both true/false, i.e. opt for phantomjs/jsDom
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          urls: ['https://self-signed.badssl.com/']
        },
        src: ['example/test.html']
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-accessibility');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['accessibility']);
};
```

**P.S.:**

- test url is an actual self-signed ssl site, so you can copy/paste the above code and test it
- only dependencies in `package.json`

  ```
  "devDependencies": {
      "grunt": "^1.0.1",
      "grunt-accessibility": "^5.0.0"
  }
  ```
- node version `v.8.9.0`

Comment: Great question! What if you try setting PhantomJS options like this:  `options: { "--ignore-ssl-errors": true, "--ssl-protocol": "any" }` (with double dashes that is?)

Comment: Tested it, but it isn't working.

Comment: @Vaviloff Any more suggestions?

Comment: Maybe make `true` in `ignore-ssl-errors` a string? `"ignore-ssl-errors": "true"`, also should try it with `--` prefix for ignore-ssl-errors since grunt-phantom just seems to concatenate arguments for command-line and PhantomJS awaits for switches with double dash.

Comment: Tried again, didn't work.

Comment: You can try with enabling the option of allow self signed certificate for localhost on the browser for the testing and development purpose. Ref - https://improveandrepeat.com/2016/09/allowing-self-signed-certificates-on-localhost-with-chrome-and-firefox/

Comment: I am trying to automate this on a integrated testing environment (not localhost) and it may or may not have chrome or other browsers installed on it (Also, issue is to allow `accessSniff` to pass the certificate which I don't think uses any browser)

Comment: Maybe you can try putting `ignore-ssl-errors` etc. options in `accessibility: { options : { ... } }`

Comment: Is using Chrome headless instead of PhantomJS an option?

Comment: @RoyTinker I'm not using phantomjs. it is an dependency of in `grunt-accessibility` -> `AccessSniff` -> `phantomjs`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can directly affect how PhantomJS is called from within another Grunt plugin *within your own Gruntfile*.

If I'm not mistaken, the only solution is to either commit a change to the grunt-accessibility package that passes an `ignore-ssl-errors` option (in the the options you pass to grunt-accessibility) upstream to PhantomJS; *or* to intercept the call to PhantomJS and inject the `ignore-ssl-errors` option.

I think the second solution will be the quickest and most expedient. You'd have to either manually modify the entry point (either `node_modules/.bin/phantomjs` or `node_modules/phantomjs/index.js`) or write a pre-run script that would modify it. In the modified .js file, you'd inject the `ignore-ssl-errors` by adding code to the top of the file that appends it to the `process.argv` array:

```
process.argv.push("--ignore-ssl-errors=true");
```

Comment: Sry, been a little busy for last couple of days. Manually setting it might be a challenge as I want it to be automated on different environments.

Comment: I tried adding the above code on top in a bunch of files, either it didn't work or gets hanged -- `node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\bin\phantomjs` , 
`node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantomjs.js` , 
`node_modules\access-sniff\dist\runners\phantom.js` , 
`node_modules\access-sniff\dist\runners\phantomExec.js` , 
`node_modules\access-sniff\bin\accessSniff.js` ,

Comment: Will be it too much of ask to test it at your end, you only need to copy above code in gruntifles and dependecies for `grunt` and `grunt-accessibility`.

Comment: Thinker, any thoughts?

Comment: @n4m31ess_c0d3r, if that didn't work, then I suggest trying the other option -- fork grunt-accessibility on GitHub, modify its gruntfile to pass that option when calling PhantomJS, and then update your package.json to point to your forked grunt-accessibility repo (use the URL to it in place of the version number).

Answer (score 0):

I always use the strict-ssl command but with a small difference.

Try to insert a *config* in your command

There will be like `npm config set strict-ssl false`

Hope this help you.